# 'Specified repository is not supported for current operating system' error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, percona

I am trying to install a Percona cluster on a VM following [this](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/8.0/install/apt.html#apt) guide, but when I get to

```
sudo percona-release setup pxc80
```

I am getting

```
Specified repository is not supported for current operating system!
```

My VM is running a ubuntu 22.04 server. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not yet a PXC for Ubuntu 22.04.  PXC is based on Percona Server, Percona Server is based on Oracle MySQL Community.  MySQL Community is not yet available from Oracle for Ubuntu 22.04.  PXC will not likely be available for Ubuntu 22.04 until 8.0.30 at the earliest.

--
George O. Lorch III
Director of Server Engineering, Percona Server for MySQL, Percona XtraDB Cluster, and Percona XtraBackup